# Does microsoft store the log for queries performed by their administrators?

Tags: security, azure, cloud, cloud-hosting

When microsofts database administrators access the sensitive information from a database, do the create a log of the activities of their administrators?

Do they have the privilege to execute 'insert' query in the hosted databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Azure is FISMA certified (Meaning it's approved for the US government to use), I'm quite sure hosted data is safe.

See here:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/gfs/archive/2010/12/02/microsoft-s-cloud-infrastructure-receives-fisma-approval.aspx

Comment: But do they maintain a log of it?

Comment: Detailed logging (including DBs) is a requirement for FISMA. Such logging is performed automatically by specialized software AND devices, not the administrators themselves.